# DNS to relay traffic between sites with internal IP in EC2

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2

I've Hadoop running on Amazon EC2 in 2 different sites, but when the components starts, they get the internal IP. I want to put the components in different sites communicating with each other using internal IP. I'm not discussing if it's safe. I've an idea to put a DNS server that translates the internal IPs to external IPs, without the components notice. So, when traffic goes with the internal IP, the DNS relays the traffic to the other site.

Is it possible? Any suggestion on how to put a DNS server in EC2?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use VPC, in which case you have control of what internal ips are assigned to your instances. Some limitations however.
2. Use elastic IPs. Connecting to the DNS name of the elastic ip will resolve to the internal IP within an aws region.

Comment: But I want that all multiple sites are interconnected. Maybe this is possible with a VPN. I don't know how to interconnect multiple sites with VPN.